# Linux shared mount point inconsistent between child and parent processes

Tags: linux, mount, linux-kernel, bind-mount

Let me try to explain the background:

In main bash:

We use

```
mount --bind /tmp/source /tmp/target
mount --make-shared /tmp/target
```

to create this shared mount point `target`

And then we use

```
unshare -m /bin/bash
```

to start a child bash. So far everything looks normal.

And then in main bash, we umount the `target` successfully.

```
umount /tmp/target
```

According this kernel document: [sharedsubtree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt). The child bash should also see the `target` has already umount although the child thread is started by `CLONE_NEWNS`(unshare -m). But the problem apprears now:

In child bash, we cat `/proc/self/mountinfo` and found `target` still exists!

```
78 48 8:3 /tmp/source /tmp/target rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/disk/by-uuid/98708f21-a59d-4b80-a85c-27b78c22e316 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

This is an unmatch behaviour in above document. In main bash, we cat `/proc/self/mountinfo` and found `taregt` has already unmount. Now we could not rmdir `target` folder because child bash is still holding this shared mount point.

```
rm -rf /tmp/target
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/target’: Device or resource busy
```

We test this on Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 6.6. Is this a kernel bug? Or I misunderstand the shared mount of linux.

Comment: Could you explain for which purpose, specifically, is `mount --make-shared` used? When there are no mounts within subdirectories, `mount --bind` is enough.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi we use it in mesos container to isolate different containers. The problem cause a bug in mesos. http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-3349

Comment: I can't test this right now, but does it help if you precede the two mount commands with the command `mount --make-shared /tmp` ?

Comment: Yes, we mark the parent of it as share mount point now.

Answer (score 0):

By default, recent versions of he `unshare` command set the mount propagation to private. Pass `--propagation unchanged` to leave it alone.